# XUbuntu 20.04 Network Device disconnecting every few minutes

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel

I am hardwired to a network.  My computer is losing internet connection every ~2 minutes for ~2 minutes.  My friend's computer, hardwired to the same network, is not having any outages.

Contents of `/var/log/apt/history.log`: https://pastebin.com/JZ9fcW8U

Output of `lspci -v`:

```
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
        Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 133
        Memory at df300000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Capabilities: <access denied>
        Kernel driver in use: e1000e
        Kernel modules: e1000e
```

Output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux JoshPC 5.4.0-97-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 13 18:22:13 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It seems like this may be a known issue: [bugzilla.kernel](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205047), [bugzilla.redhat](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1787026).

I believe I updated my system a few days ago and the problem started today.

What should I do to stop this problem from continuing?

**Attempted solutions and results:**

1. **Failed**: Change MTU from Automatic to 1492 in network connection settings GUI interface.
2. **Failed**: Change link negotiation from "Ignore" to "Manual"
3. **Failed**: Change link negotiation from "Ignore" to "Automatic"
4. **Failed**: Install the driver here: https://github.com/koljah-de/e1000e-dkms-debian
5. **Failed**: Change ethernet cable.
6. **Failed**: Update kernel stack to HWE 5.13 Kernel (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Server).  I successfully upgraded the kernel but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: You weren't specific as to which kernel stack you're using (*Ubuntu LTS releases have two kernels stack choices + potentially OEM options*), but one of the kernel bug reports only mentions 5.3 & 5.4RC status kernels; so have you tried the much newer HWE stack? (*it contains far newer than is mentioned in that report*)

Comment: 5.4.0-97-generic #110-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jan 13 18:22:13 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linu

Comment: 5.4 is the GA kernel stack; 5.13 is the kernel currently being used if you're using the HWE kernel stack; ie. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: @guiverc: I haven't messed with drivers or the kernel at all. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 back in May of 2020, give or take, and done updates as prompted. My network device worked fine until today. I am happy with staying away from bleeding edge kernels. Is there instead a way to identify which update broke this and revert it?

Comment: Ubuntu LTS releases come with two kernel stack choices; for Ubuntu Server the default can be set at install time but if that option is left to default the GA stack is used; with Ubuntu Desktop the HWE is the default; with *flavors* it's GA for 20.04 & 20.04.1 media, and HWE for 20.04.2 & later media... ie. two choices (the link I gave is one option; but I'd follow what @N0rbert provided & have up-voted it..) FYI: To test the other kernel stack; I'd likely use *live* media rather than install; ie. not impact your existing install, but it'll depend somewhat on your media given Server ISOs use GA

Comment: I installed N0rbert's link's driver and restarted. Let's see how it goes.

Comment: Did not work. I got about 3 minutes of network before it disconnected.

Comment: Then try [HWE 5.13 kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack#Server). And maybe check Ethernet cable.

Comment: Why aren't we talking about just undoing whatever happened ~3 days ago? The system ran fine for nearly two years.

Comment: Tried swapping the wire. Strangely things were stable for about 15 minutes, and then it started cycling again.

Comment: Tried upgrading the kernel as indicated. Problem persists.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem using a 20.04 Live USB's "Try Ubuntu" environment?