# How to configure a Rosewill RC400-LX network card for Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, adapter

I have been having an intermittent and recurring problem with my onboard network adapter for the past year or two: [XUbuntu 20.04 Network Device disconnecting every few minutes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1391701/xubuntu-20-04-network-device-disconnecting-every-few-minutes). It won't happen for months at a time, and then it'll start up for a week or two, and then go away. I can't figure out the cause. I upgraded from 20.04 to 22.04 and it persisted. (I think it has something to do with one of my storage hard-drives getting nearly full, but I'm not trying to troubleshoot that problem now).

Rather than continue to wrestle with this issue, I decided to buy a new network card and plug it in and use that, hopefully solving the problem.

I bought a [Rosewill RC400-LX](https://www.rosewill.com/legacy2t/product/rosewill-rc-400-lx-network-adapter-10-100-1000-mbps-pci-1-x-rj45/). I plugged it in and turned on the computer, expecting it to just work. Instead, I had no connection and the network configuration icon in my system tray didn't launch. Not knowing how to launch that manually, I plugged the wire back into the onboard network adapter and restarted. I got internet. I then plugged back into the new adapter and there was no internet.

I tried going to "edit connections" and creating a new connection. When I click the "device" drop down, only the old card shows, not the new one.

I typed `lspci -v` and I do not see the new adapter listed there.

I spent $15 or $25 on this new card and if it isn't a good choice for compatibility with linux I'm happy to buy another one that is more linux compatible.

Alternatively, if there's something I need to do to get this card configured in, please let me know and I'll do it.

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Did you install a Ubuntu driver or look to see if this card needs a Ubuntu driver by asking the maker of the card?

Comment: I went to their website and looked for drivers. All they had was a very outdated driver for kernels 2.4.x and 2.2.x. Then I posted here.

Comment: I am asking how to install a Ubuntu driver. I don't know how to identify the right package or find it if it's not in the standard repository.

Comment: The chipset ihas native support for almost a decade. Drivers AREN'T the problem here. The problem is the card not being detected at all.  It can be a setting in BIOS/UEFI or the card itself is faulty. On top of that the problem you're trying to solve is way more likely to be related with the device you're connecting to than with the network chipset, integrated or in an add-on card.

Comment: That is useful information, thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's my computer and not the router. I have two computers running ubuntu hooked up to the router and only this one drops. I swapped which port they were plugged into and it persisted. I replaced this wire and it persisted.